# Assign template to a post type via Javascript

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I was reading the Gutenberg documentation and I came across this:
https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/templates/#existing-post-types

After a good amount of research, I found out that I can tap into the Post Object (https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/data/data-core-editor/#getcurrentpost), but I can't find a Post Type Object, which I'm guessing that's what I need.

Is there a way to assign a template via Javascript on runtime?